# Angular Material Datepicker - Set selected date form value to ISOSTRING 8601 with offset

Tags: angular, angular-material

I've searched for an answer for too long today, so i decided to ask here instead. 
Is it possible to set/modify the output value after selecting a day in the material datepicker? Right now it returns a date object, so if this gets send to the server it will get converted to a UTC date string because of tthe toJSON method (which calls Date.toISOString). Unfortunately this removes the time offset i need to send to the server.

I know i could just write a helper function, which can convert my date object into the desired formatted string, so that i could use this on every date value before i send it to the server. But i want to know, if there is a more elegant, global approach using the material API? I thought NativeDateAdapter could be a way, but as far as understand, this is helping only in formatting the UI output value. Or am i wrong?

Any help or hint would be really cool - right now i'm a bit stuck.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you try @angular/material-moment-adapter

Comment: Yes, I looked into the MomentDateAdapter, but couldn’t find a way to modify the resulting output (to a string) which is set as the form value. Also i would like to go without the extra dependency moment.js, because right now I’m using date-fns in the project already.